# Converting an in memory .raw vector to TIFF data

Tags: c++, opencv, tiff

Not sure if this is a duplicate, but after days of searching without any luck, I figured I'd ask. I have a vector of .raw image data, which needs to be converted to a TIF cv::Mat. I have tried multiple times to do this with no luck. I know there are tools such as raw2tiff that handle this outisde of memory, but I want to stay in memory.

Is there any such way of doing this?

Comment: You will need to know the dimensions, the number of channels (RGB or RGBA or mono/greyscale) and the data type (i.e. unsigned 8 bit, float etc). Bear in mind there is no such thing as a TIF Mat. The image is encoded to TIF or other format only when writing to disk/saving.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44453382/2836621 refers.